# Wordpress Custom post type and permalink

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, wordpress, permalinks

I have these two statements in my init

```
add_rewrite_tag('%cirrus_url%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^listings/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cirrus_url=$matches[2]','top');
```

Using the parse_request filter, I can see that my rule is being matched and used.

However, Wordpress is forwarding the page, so all my /vars/at/the/end are lost when the page renders.

When I output something from the query_var filter, I get a Headers already sent message, so I know that wordpress is trying to forward the page.

http://1parkplace.mysharedvision.com/dev/listings/travis-heights-test/

If you put something at the end like:
http://1parkplace.mysharedvision.com/dev/listings/travis-heights-test/what-is-this/

You'll see what I mean.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first link return another statement: `"listings/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$"`

Comment: Yeah, that is matching the wordpress build in regex.  But when I add stuff to the end, it matches my regex, but the tries to forward the page

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
add_rewrite_tag('%cirrus_url%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('listings/([^/]*)(/[^/]+)?$/?','index.php?cirrus_posts=$matches[1]&cirrus_url=$matches[2]','top');
```

My custom post type was cirrus_posts so I just looked at wordpress' `<?php var_dump($wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules()); ?>`

To see what it was doing and that let me to the right thing